# $ conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3　でエラー

Tags: opencv, anaconda, conda

Python 3.x 系の Anaconda 上で OpenCV 3.x を使おうとしたところ、エラーで失敗しました。

下記の様なエラーにはどう対応すれば良いのでしょうか？

```
$ conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo opencv3


Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - opencv3 -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Comment: OpenCV 3.x を Anaconda 上で使いたいだけなのか、menpo/opencv3 をインストールしたいのか、どちらでしょうか？

Comment: また、Python 3.x 系で使いたいのか、Python 2.x 系で使いたいのか、どちらでしょうか？　Anaconda 自体はどちらでインストールしましたか？

Comment: OpenCV 3.xをanacondaで使えれば嬉しいです。Pythonは3.xで使おうと考えております。

Answer (score 2):

本家 Stack Overflow の ["Can't install OpenCV3 on Anaconda3 python3.6 on macOS"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41873941/5989200) で報告されている問題と同一だと思います。この conflict は、Anaconda によってインストールされている Python 3.6 が新しいバージョンであり、既存のパッケージが追従できていないために発生しています。

[Nehal J Wani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005215/nehal-j-wani) さんの[回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41876530/5989200)などを参考にまとめると、ひとまず3つの対応策があります。

- 自分で OpenCV をビルドし、パッケージを作る。 https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock
- Python 3.5 の [conda envirionment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html) を作り、その中で [menpo/opencv3](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3) などのパッケージを使って OpenCV 3.x をインストールする。

  ```sh
  # 現在の Python のバージョンを確認
  $ conda list| grep python
  python           3.6.1        2
  # Python 3.5.x の environment を作成し、activate
  $ conda create -n opencv3 python=3.5
  $ source activate opencv3
  # 現在の Python のバージョンを確認
  $ conda list| grep python
  python           3.5.2        2
  # この環境に menpo/opencv3 をインストール
  $ conda install -c menpo opencv3
  ```
- [conda-forge の opencv パッケージ](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv)を利用する。

  ```sh
  $ conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3
  ```

Ubuntu では既に Python 3.6.1 + OpenCV 3.2.0 が conda-forge でも menpo でも利用できるので、macOS 用にもその内パッケージが用意されるかもしれませんが、それまでは上のような方法をとる必要があります。現在の対応状況は、`conda search` コマンドや、[Anaconda Cloud の Files タブ](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3/files)で確認することができます (デフォルトのパッケージについては[こちら](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/packages/pkg-docs)で確認できます)。

なお、インストールした後、次のように OpenCV のバージョンが確認できます。

```py
import cv2
print(cv2.__version__)
```